# JSON Array For Each Loop Php

Tags: php, json

I am looking at how to condense this down into a proper "for loop" which means it runs the text, value, and id fields for the length of the json array.

This works but is not dynamic. there has to be a way to do this and I just cant find an example how beyond the point I'm at.

```
                array(
                "text" => $data[3]['name'],
                "value" => $data[3]['slug'],
                "id" => "id-2"
            )
```

Everything I have found so far has been useful but nothing past this point and I'm sure it's a simple answer.

what this does is get all the entries within a taxonomy to populate a drop-down form's field

```
function myfunction() {

    $request = wp_remote_get( 'https://shatner/wp-json/wpas-api/v1/enterprize-crew?type=name' );

    if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
        return false; // Bail early
    }

$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );

$data = json_decode( $body, true );
    $elementCount  = count($data);
    foreach($data as $key['name'] => $value) {
     
        $options = array(
            array(
                "text" => $data[0]['name'],
                "value" => $data[0]['slug'],
                "id" => "id-1"
            ),
            array(
                "text" => $data[1]['name'],
                "value" => $data[1]['slug'],
                "id" => "id-2"
            ),
                            
            array(
                "text" => $data[2]['name'],
                "value" => $data[2]['slug'],
                "id" => "id-1"
            ),
            array(
                "text" => $data[3]['name'],
                "value" => $data[3]['slug'],
                "id" => "id-2"
            )
        );
        
        return $options;
    }
```

}

Comment: Please add result of 'var_dump($data);'. And "id" tags should be really `id-1, id-2, id-1, id-2` or `id-1, id-2, id-3, id-4`?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php 

Not sure what you mean, the json values are already there and I can grab the values if I hardcode the references, what I'm trying to do is make it dynamic through a loop

Yes, I caught that. those values don't matter quite yet until I get this part working. Im using ex contact form and it uses those id values to trigger conditionals in the form.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a json instance, but we assume your json is a list of name and slug, so you can do the following:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $options[] = ["text" => $value['name'], "value" => $value['slug'], "id" => "id-" . ($key + 1)];
}
```

Comment: Would this replace the entire for each loop I already have?

Comment: Yes, give it a try